# What are some good reasons to switch to jQuery 1.4

Tags: jquery

I am currently running 1.3.2, and i have no problems with it so far. Are there any good reasons why i should have a look at jQuery 1.4.

I know you don't know what type of application i have, but maybe there are some mayor benefits that suits every developer.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pros:

2. Speed - every good js framework is speedier each release
3. Support - old version is not being fixed any more ;)
4. New features - mentioned third, cause You might not need them
5. The docs page changed with 1.4 version
6. There's not much to learn to switch over

**cons:** [nobody mentioned before]

2. Most old plugins that are not developed anymore might not work
3. Even some new plugins will show up with some latency
4. Some plugins' behaviours change with 1.4 and You'll have to learn and change Your code [like in BBQ plugin]
5. Some tricky bits of Your own code might not work

Comment: As a rule I have rarely seen pro #1 borne out in software frameworks. If jQuery is getting speedier, then bravo...

Comment: Well Yes - it is. All important javascript frameworks are being optimized quite well. I remember animating 5 divs floating around the page with about 0,5 FPS with jquery 1.0. But It was my fault too ;)

Answer (score 0):

See **[jQuery 1.4 Released: The 15 New Features you Must Know](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/jquery-1-4-released-the-15-new-features-you-must-know/)**

**[jQuery 1.4 Released: Sneak Peek on New Features and Enhancements](http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2010/01/jquery-1.4-released-sneak-peek-on-new-features-and-enhancements.html)**

Answer (score 0):

There are many benefits:
http://jquery14.com/day-01/jquery-14

Such as faster performance, lots of tweaks, etc...

But I think the best reason, like most popular technologies, is that sooner or later everyone is going to be using 1.4x and you'll have to learn it, so you should start new projects with it so you can be on the curve.

Comment: Yes i guess i have to switch over one day. i was not aware of the optimizations tho, that is a huge +